# runners on base and line out

Tags: rules

We had runners on 1st and 3rd with 1 out.  While stealing second, the ball was lined to 2b.  The second baseman did not touch the runner who is now standing on second.  They slowly walk over to tag the runner.  The runner on third was tagged up and decided to take home.  He scored before the out was recorded at second.  It was counted a run and I believe that was the right call but looking for thoughts.  50 years old and never saw that one before.

Comment: To clarify, is this baseball or softball? It may not make a difference, but it would helpful for tagging reasons.

Answer (score 4):

When the ball was caught (on the fly) by 2B, the batter was out.  This means there is no force.  (Even though 1R can be put out by tagging first base).

This is then a time play and the run counts if plate is reached before the third out is recorded.

This play is very similar to one of the approved rulings for [5.08(b)](https://img.mlbstatic.com/mlb-images/image/upload/mlb/wqn5ah4c3qtivwx3jatm.pdf), which covers scoring.

> APPROVED RULING: One out, Jones on third, Smith on first, and Brown
> flies out to right field. Two outs. Jones tags up and scores after the
> catch. Smith attempted to return to first but the right fielder’s
> throw beat him to the base. Three outs. But Jones scored before the
> throw to catch Smith reached first base, hence Jones’ run counts. It
> was not a force play.